# What is the antonym for heavy makeup?

Tags: grammar, antonyms

> She has a **heavy** makeup.
>
> She has a **light** makeup.

What is the antonym for heavy makeup?

Comment: "Light makeup" sounds right to me.

Comment: No article is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly. I think 'light makeup' is okay there.

That's because when it comes to shading or contrast, we use 'light' to mean 'less' in terms of contrast or layers.

I know this because in some schools here, they define 'girls with light makeup' is allowed.

---

A suggestion: Generally, we use 'wear/put on/apply' with makeup. And, it is 'uncountable'. So, *"She wears/puts on heavy/light makeup.

Comment: +1 for dropping the article.  One can also use the verb "apply": "The artist applied some grisly makeup to the actor playing the zombie."

Comment: @TRomano ah, I missed it. Edited, added! thnaks :)

Comment: Also, we ladies use "natural makeup" or "natural-looking makeup" to describe cosmetics that are (or look like they are!) lightly applied. For example "She wore natural makeup during the week, but on the weekends she liked to apply heavier makeup".

Comment: @ColleenV hey, nice point. And I din' know you are a lady! In many of my comments, I might have addressed you as a 'man'. Kindly excuse that. :)

Comment: No worries - life is too short to get offended by innocent mistakes.  Just FYI, [Colleen](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/colleen) is an unambiguously feminine name when written, although sometimes when a person unfamiliar with it tries to pronounce it, the spoken version can be confused with [Colin](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/colin).

Comment: I never knew this! Colleen! @ColleenV :)